# MYSQL - Storing unicode characters (emoji) in TEXT column

Tags: mysql, unicode, character-encoding

When trying to insert a unicode emoji character () to a MYSQL table, the insert fails due to the error;

```
Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x8E\\xF0\\x9F...' for column 'Title' at row 1
```

From what I've red about this issue, it's apparently caused by the tables default character set, and possible the columns default character set, being set incorrectly. [This post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161460/error-1366-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x98-x8a-x0ac-for-column-text-bo) suggests to use `utf8mb4`, which I've tried, but the insert is still failing.

Here's my table configuration;

```
CREATE TABLE `TestTable` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `InsertDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Title` text,
  `Description` text,
  `Info` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `xId_TestTablePK` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2191 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Note that the `Title` and `Text` columns dont have an explicitly stated character set. Initially I had no default table character set, and had these two columns were setup with `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4`. However, when I altered the table's default charset to the same, they were removed (presumably because the columns inherit the type from the table?)

Can anyone please help me understand how I can store these unicode values in my table?

Its worth noting that I'm on Windows, trying to perform this insert on the MYSQL Workbench. I have also tried using C# to insert into the database, specifying the character set with `CHARSET=utf8mb4`, however this returned the same error.

EDIT

To try and insert this data, I am executing the following;

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (Title) SELECT '';
```

[image]

Edit

Not sure if this is relevant or not, but my database is also set up with the same default character set;

```
CREATE DATABASE `TestDB` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 */;
```

Comment: @daxim, apologies - fixed now.

Comment: How did you fix it?  By SET NAMES utf8mb4?  By changing the connection parameters?

Comment: @RickJames, no I just fixed the broken link that was reported in a comment, which seems to have since been removed. This issue is still ongoing.

Comment: Then remove your comments so we don't get confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *connection* needs to establish that the *client* is talking `utf8mb4`, not just `utf8`.  This involves changing the parameters used at connection time.  Or executing `SET NAMES utf8mb4` just after connecting.